# meta name="viewport" - Disable rotation, zooming & swiping all together

Tags: html, ios, iphone

We're developing a custom web app that should run on iOS *only*. The app is deployed as a web site and then a "home icon" is added from Safari so it behaves like an app.

**We define app behaviour as**

- No zooming *(already working)*
- No screen rotation
- No vertical swiping

The body is `640x1096` pixels. This is the iPhone 5s resolution *(excluding the top iOS bar).*

```
width=device-width, initial-scale=.5, user-scalable=no
```

For some reason, `initial-scale` has to be set to **.5** instead of **1** so the web site will fit exactly into the space of the iPhone. **Why?**

It's already not-zoomable, but you can still **rotate** the screen and **swipe vertically**, which kind-of destroys the "feeling" of an app. There actually is nothing to swipe on the y-axis, so we might as well get rid of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiping can be entirely disabled using [TouchSwipe](http://www.awwwards.com/touchswipe-a-jquery-plugin-for-touch-and-gesture-based-interaction.html). You can then touch anywhere you want and the web app is not swiped anywhere.

```
$('html').swipe
({
    fingers: 'all',
    swipe: function() { }
});
```

And rotation can be disabled like so:

```
$(function()
{
    window.onorientationchange = OrientationChanged;
    window.setTimeout(OrientationChanged, 0);
}
function OrientationChanged(e)
{
    $('body').css('-webkit-transform', window.orientation % 180 == 0 ? '' : 'rotate(-90deg)');
}
```